# Commenting blocks of code in Visual Studio Code in .erb files

Tags: visual-studio-code, erb

How to configure Visual Studio Code to comment out blocks of code which consist of ruby and html tags in .erb files as it works in Rubymine?
I want vs code to insert `#` after all the `<%` and `<!--` and `-->` around all the html tags when I highlight a block of code and press *Cmd + /*

I have this code:

```
      <% if !something %>
        <div>
          <%= link_to "Link", some_path, class: "link" %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
```

When I highlight this block and press *Cmd + /*  I get:

```
      <%# <% if !something %>
        <div>
          <%= link_to "Link", some_path, class: "link" %>
        </div>
      <% end %> %>
```

So it only inserts the `#` into the first line and that's all.

What I want to see as a result of highlighting and pressing *Cmd + /*:

```
      <%# if !something %>
<!--        <div>-->
          <%#= link_to "Link", some_path, class: "link" %>
<!--        </div>-->
      <%# end %>
```

Comment: Are the `<!--` comment characters at the very beginning of the line or are they indented?

Comment: At the beginning.